# Laying out views in a ScrollView, can't control layout and scroll direction independently

Tags: titanium

I had a window that used `layout: 'horizontal'` and when I added child views, each using `width: '50%'`, it was great, they all just filled in like a 2-column table.

However, I realized I needed the content to scroll, so I added a scrollview to the window, and added my child views to the scrollview - but it didn't work. When I use `layout: 'horizontal'` on the scrollview, it tries to make the content scroll horizontally - where all of the child views are on one row (only first 2 are seen on UI). If I change it to `layout: 'vertical'`, it scrolls properly, but the views are laid out in a 1-column format (one on-top of another)

```
var deals_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Deals',
    layout: 'horizontal'
  });

  var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    layout: 'horizontal',
    scrollType: 'vertical',
    contentWidth: '100%',
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'

  });
  deals_window.add(scrollView);
```

How can I get the scrollView to use 'horizontal' layout behavior, while scrolling vertically...?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use horizontal layout. Try this:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
   layout: 'vertical',
   height: Ti.UI.FILL
});

var row = Ti.UI.createView({
   height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: "50%",
    left: 0
});

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: "50%",
    right: 0
});

row.add(view1);
row.add(view2);

scrollView.add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the property horizontalWrap:true of scrollView. It may help you!

Here is code:

```
//window
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
//scrollView
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({}i
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    contentWidth: '100%',
    layout: 'horizontal',
    horizontalWrap: true,
    scrollType: 'vertical'
);
win.add(scrollView);
//item in scrollView
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    var itemLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        font:{
            fontSize: '18'
        },
        left: '2.5%',
        width: '30%',
        color: 'black',
        height: '90'
        borderRadius: 5,
        textAlign: 'center',
        text: 'item '+(i+1),
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    });
    scrollView.add(itemLabel);
}
```

Well, in this way it really work, however, there's a problem with **scrollView** when it can scroll the part of the last row will be covered. So, I do not recommend you apply this way to solve your problem. You can try more better ***UI Component*** like **TableView** or **ListView**, for **TableView** just put any numbers of the item you want in **TableViewRow**, and for **ListView** just defined a **ItemTemplate** which contains several items you want. If you need more details, just write email to me: *frankjorsn@gmail.com*